# Terminal not answering

Tags: bash, terminal

I began noticing random `bash: some_command: command not found` on startup of `bash` so I tried switching to `sh`, but it also said `bash: sh: command not found` so I tried to restart bash and yet, `bash: bash: command not found` and I haven't changed any `bash` files. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `PATH` variable is not set or empty?

Bash uses `PATH` environment variable to search for commands, unless an absolute path is used. It is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands: try `man bash`

You should try to display the list of directories where bash is looking for command with:

```
printf "%s\n" "${PATH}"
```

By default on my ubuntu 20.04 LTS, the above command output is:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: and i am on cloud shell debian

Comment: im just reinstalling